# Sql developer problem. No ocijdbc21 in java.library.path

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I downloaded Oracle 19c DBMS. Then I downloaded Sql Developer. When I try to add a new connection, I get the message [image]

How do I get past this. I have seen some other threads on this but none of the solutions that I understand seem to fix it. I need to keep the connection type as local. Is there somewhere I can go and just adjust this path?

***EDIT***
I used just a basic connection and the name database name in the service name box and it worked. The initial setup instructions I had were dated and not set up for 19c. One of the comments in the answer below suggested this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 20.4.1 and bequeath connection you must have a 21c instant client as we're using a 21c jdbc driver.

If you're not on Linux, that means you'll need version 20.4.0 so you can use a 19c Instant Client.

Windows 21c Clients should be available later this Summer.

*Edit/Update: Version 21.2.1 now supports 19c and 21c Clients. 21c Instant Clients are rolling out across supported platforms. Currently avail for Linux, soon to include Windows and OS X.*

Comment: When I dig into the files, I see a "Orasqlic18.dll" file. Is this relevant?

Comment: Don't use bequeath connection, use basic. As long as your listener is running, you'll be fine.

Comment: If you have to use bequeath, find an older version of sqld developer

Comment: Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
  (CONNECTION_ID=X6TeLPVnTXCG4vqAihFNTg==)

Comment: Don't use SID, use service

Comment: For sys you need to set role as SYSDBA, not normal

Comment: I can give that a try. My concern starts to be though that if I deviate from the teacher's instructions too much, it will come back to bite me in the future.

Comment: I'm trying to help, you can't connect bequeath without a 21c client and you cannot connect as sys w/o using SYSDBA ... Go get version 20.4.0 and you'll be fine

Comment: Find out the service name for your db, and just use a basic connection... bequeath is a very limited/specific use case - and you can kinda see why

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the DB connection changed from Network Alias to Connect Identifier post a company pushed update, simple fix after hours /days of trouble shooting.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this error with Oracle SQL Developer and the fix for us was to in Oracle SQL Developer:

- Tools -> Preferences
- In the tree view on the left Expand Database and select Advanced
- In Use Oracle Client click Configure...
- Set the path to your Oracle home (should looks something like `C:\Path\To\Oracle\19.n`)
- Check the Use Oracle Client box
- In the Tnsnames Directory set it to the folder containing the tnsnames.ora file (should looks something like `C:\Path\To\Oracle\19.n\network\admin`)
- Click OK
- Relaunch Oracle SQL Developer